# How to get the original message's message field through FbGraph /me/inbox?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, message, inbox, subject

I am trying to get the original message content from the /me/inbox through the API. I have authorized the read_inbox permission and got a bunch of message objects back. However, each of the message has no Subject nor Message (content). But it does contain comments which include a list of comments with the comment's message content.

Is this a permission issue? Or am I using the API wrong?

Message example below (using fake content for privacy reason.)

```
{
  "id": "97654321", 
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Luke C.", 
        "id": "12346"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Mark D.", 
        "id": "12345"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "updated_time": "2013-01-31T19:10:17+0000", 
  "unread": 0, 
  "unseen": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon asking my colleague who have worked with FBgraph api for sometime already. It seems like the fbgraph inbox does behaved like this for a while and there does not seem to have any intention to fix it. And I also noticed that the me/outbox would behave as expected where a 'from'

Thus, I have moved onto using FQL to replace the me/inbox api:

```
SELECT body, recipients, sender, thread_id, message_id
FROM unified_message where thread_id IN 
(SELECT thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE folder = 'inbox')
```

If anyone know why FbGraph api does not work, please still help contribute to this question.